# If PATH is unset, my find_path should stop working but I am getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c, path, environment-variables

```
char *find_path(char **envp) 
{
    if (envp == NULL || *envp == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (ft_strncmp("PATH=", *envp, 5))
        envp++; 
    return (*envp + 5);
}
```

I tried `envp` to be zero, also tried comparing string of `PATH` not found in `envp` (environmental variable) using `strcmp` but it causes the segmentation fault.

I want to test if we unset the `PATH`, I want to return the function as normal and not cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Besides your issue with your `if` conditions, how do you address the case that `PATH` is not set? What does "should stop working" mean? If you don't find it, you will iterate beyond the limit of the array of pointers to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- bad indentation: it made the code hard to read for both you and the next programmer. Your school might enforce local coding style rules by giving a fail mark (0) for badly indented code.
- the tests `envp = NULL` and `*envp = NULL` are incorrect: the `=` operator **sets** `envp` to `NULL` and this evaluated to false, then `||` attempts to set `*envp` to `NULL`, causing the segmentation fault as `*envp` is now a null pointer. You should use `==` instead of `=`
- The `while` loop does not have a proper ending condition: if `envp` reaches the end of the `environ` array, `*envp` will be a null pointer, potentially causing `ft_strncmp` to crash (depending if it tests for null pointers or not). You should iterate while the `*envp` is non null and return `*envp + 5` if the comparison returns `0`. This removes the need for the second initial test.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *find_path(char **envp) {
    if (envp) {
        while (*envp) {
            if (ft_strncmp("PATH=", *envp, 5) == 0)
                return *envp + 5;
            envp++;
        }
    }
    // no environment or PATH not found: return a null pointer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was my negligence that I posted a code without reviewing it properly and the indentation issue. This fixed the issue, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Please format your code before posting; it's difficult to read when it's weirdly indented like that.

To check for equality in C, you must use `==`, not `=`. `=` will set `envp` to `NULL` and return its new value. Since this value is 0, the `if` clause will be evaluated to `false` and `return 0` won't execute. Also, you should have tested what happens if `envp` *isn't* 0 before assuming that's the problem. Your code fragment causes a segmentation fault no matter what value `envp` is entering the function, since it's changed to `NULL` anyways.

```
char *find_path(char **envp)
{
    if (envp == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (*envp == NULL)
        return 0;
    while(ft_strncmp("PATH=", *envp, 5))
        envp++; 
    return (*envp + 5);
}
```

Comment: That solves half the problems. If `PATH` is not found for some reason, you will iterate until `envp` points to a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Thank you, ill fix the indentation but the problem still persisted because of the envp++ which lead to segmentation fault. :) Again, thank you :)